# Add a search box to the tags synonyms pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, tag-synonyms

Currently the [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) consist of eight pages. It would be *way* easier to find a specific tag when a search box is added, like on the [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page.

Comment: Real Life needs a search box.

Comment: If you're looking for a specific tag, why wouldn't you just go to that tag's info page?

Comment: @Michael: You're right. It only is not that clear that the tag leads to a master tag, but that's another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah ... this was driving me nuts as a moderator ... added a filter box

Comment: will be deployed today

Answer (score 0):

We need this functionality to see if a tag has a synonym up for a vote.
The synonym page for the Tag only says that is has no approved synonyms.